# How to run a file after a user successfully passes discord Oauth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a file called `discordauth.js` which opens up discord auth and allows the user to authorize themself. I now need to check if the user has the `Member` role and then run the file `index.js`. I don't know if this helps but when I authorize I receive this is the console

```
  access_token: 'access-token',
  expires_in: 604800,
  refresh_token: 'refresh-token,
  scope: 'identify email guilds',
  token_type: 'Bearer'
}
{
  id: 'user-id',
  username: 'users name',
  avatar: 'avatar id',
  discriminator: 'discord tag',
  public_flags: 64,
  flags: 64,
  email: 'users email',
  verified: true,
  locale: 'en-US',
  mfa_enabled: true,
  premium_type: 1
}
```

I have filtered all of my tokens and just put in placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the server using the server ID, then get the member using the user ID from the OAuth, before checking if the member has the *Member* role.

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(/* guild ID */);
const member = await guild.members.fetch(/* member ID from OAuth */);
const hasRole = member.roles.cache.has('Member');

if (hasRole) {
  // do stuff
}
```

**References:**

- [`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds)
- [`GuildManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache)
- [`Collection.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)
- [`Guild.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members)
- [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)
- [`GuildMember.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)
- [`GuildMemberRoleManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache)
- [`Collection.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has)